# Clarification for V(ref) for TPS212x

Tags: power-supply, datasheet

I’m having a hard time figuring out the manual switching capabilities of the [TPS212x](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2120.pdf?ts=1681058434189&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fpower-management%252Fpower-switches%252Fpower-muxes%252Fproducts.html) Power MUX. As per the datasheet, it supports automatic, manual as well as both i.e. automatic but can be overridden (manual).

The two pins that I can't seem to understand the working of are PR1 and CP2 (which is only present in TPS2121 & not TPS2120).

**Q** Still, need to understand what input is provided to CP2 pin of the IC? Is it the same as PR1?
Edit: Can be connected to GPIO for Manual switching. Still need clarification for other use cases.

*Can be connected to GPIO(XREF), XCOMP (IN2), and GND as well.*

*Solved* **Q.** What is switchover voltage? (Can't be V(ref) because it is predetermined and is 1.06 V in this case).

As seen in datasheet 'CP2 enables comparator operation *and is compared to PR1 to set switchover voltage*' what if **PR1 is GND**?

[image]

As per the datasheet
[image]

[image]
[image]

For 2120 we have a SEL pin which can be connected to a microcontroller to override automatic operation. So this enables it to have **MANUAL** switching.

*Solved* **Q.** Without the presence of SEL pin, how does TPS2121 support manual switching?

*Solved* **Q.** Understanding t(fsw)

Sol. When CP2 >= 1.06 V then it'll take me ~5 us time to switch from either of the power supplies to the other one. Is this conclusion correct? (*Yes*)

[image]

Comment: Please read table 9-3 in the data sheet and let me know if you still are confused.

Comment: 'If CP2 is pulled low, then the TPS2121 ignores this pin' -> I think this answers if PR1 is GND.
|||
'If both inputs are valid, CP2 is low, and PR1 is pulled high, (higher than VREF, 1.06-V typical), then IN1 isused.'-> V(ref) is some standard value 1.06V (pre-determined)
|||
CP2 >= V(ref) where V(ref) is 1.06V. Now this in context to the last image in the main post. Now since this is satisfied it can take me 5us to go from Vin1 to Vin2 and vice versa?


CP2 is comparator output right?

Comment: Can't edit the above comment, i meant to say CP2 is the input to the comparator, which is the same as PR1

Comment: If I were you I'd fully revise the question based on the knowledge gained from table 9-3 so that your residual questions are clearer.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm almost at the end of the datasheet. Things got pretty straightforward as I approached the end. This is only my second datasheet ever. I'm tempted to read the detailed part first and then the actual characteristics from now on lol.

Comment: Good man @harkirat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q. What input is provided to CP2 pin of the IC?

Sol. Can be connected to GPIO(XREF), XCOMP (IN2), and GND as well.

Q. Understanding t(fsw)

Sol. When CP2 >= V(ref), then fast switching is enabled, only on TPS2121.

Q. Without the presence of SEL pin, how does TPS2121 support manual switching?

Sol. CP2 pin can be connected via the GPIO pin of a microcontroller, which then ditches then conventional PR1/VREF standard for switching among input Power Supply(s).

Q. What is switchover voltage?

Sol. V(out) at which we'd want to switch to the redundant/backup power supply.